# User NavigatorState to clear all routes and push on home route

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Firebase messaging` in my app. At anytime I assume that `FirebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged`
callback could be invoked if the sign in state changes. When this happens I want to reset the app back to the home (login) screen.

To do this I am using the following code:

```
// navigatorKey is of type GlobalKey<NavigatorState> because in the firebase callback I dont have a context
navigatorKey.currentState.popUntil((Route<dynamic> route) => false);
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(NavBoss.ENTRY_ROUTE);
```

When a log in occurs, I pushReplacement so the home screen no longer exists on the route stack. So I want to pop until all the routes are gone, and then push on the home (login) screen back on.

But when I execute this code I get an error...

> I/flutter (18716): #0      ListMixin.lastWhere
> (dart:collection/list.dart:163:5) I/flutter (18716): #1
> NavigatorState.popUntil
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3620:32)

Is there a way I can clear all the routes on the stack using NavigatorState?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A model which globally provides [NavigatorState]'s functionality.
///
/// Even if a page is inside of nesting navigators, you can go outside
/// of the nesting navigator to use outside [NavigatorState] by [AppNavigator].
///
/// # Usage
///
/// ```dart
/// final appNavigator = Provider.of<AppNavigator>(context, listen:false);
/// appNavigator.push(SamplePage.routeName);
/// ```
class AppNavigator {
  AppNavigator({
    @required this.navigatorKey,
  });

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  /// [Navigator] which is held by [AppNavigator]
  NavigatorState get _navigator => navigatorKey.currentState;

  /// Pushes page by [routeName].
  ///
  /// This is same as [Navigator.pushNamed].
  void push(String routeName, {Object arguments}) =>
      _navigator.pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);

  /// Pushes page by [routeName] and remove all pages.
  ///
  /// This is same as [Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil].
  void pushAndRemoveAllPage(String routeName, {Object arguments}) =>
      _navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        routeName,
        (route) => false,
        arguments: arguments,
      );

  /// Replaces current page and Pushes page by [routeName].
  ///
  /// This is same as [Navigator.pushReplacementNamed].
  void pushReplacement(String routeName, {Object arguments}) =>
      _navigator.pushReplacementNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments);

  /// Pops page if it can pop.
  ///
  /// This is same as [Navigator.maybePop].
  void pop() => _navigator.maybePop();
}
````

Then the materialapp will look like
use provider

```
Provider(
          lazy: false,
          create: (_) => AppNavigator(
            navigatorKey: GlobalKey(debugLabel: "for Global Navigation"),
          ),
        ),
```

finally in material app

```
 return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey:
          Provider.of<AppNavigator>(context, listen: false).navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute:
          Provider.of<GlobalRouter>(context, listen: false).onGenerateRoute,
      home: () {
        return const SplashPage();
      }(),
    );
```

finally use it like

```
appNavigator.push(SamplePage.routeName);
```